# Unable to create Token directory for Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to connect to Google Drive from an Android app that will eventually download audio tracks from the Drive. I am unable to create the /token/ directory for authentication.

I have split up the process of creating the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` to show how far the process is getting before failing.  I have also attempted to pre-create the /token/ directory and this also fails.

This is the relevant code.
Because I am using internal storage, no permissions have been requested in the manifest file.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("LOGLEARN", "Starting AlarmReceiver");
        Drive service;
        try {
            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName("Morning Learning")
                    .build();

            FileList result = service.files().list()
                    .setPageSize(10)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    .execute();
            List<File> files = result.getFiles();
            if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(DEBUG,"No files found.");
            } else {
                Log.i(DEBUG, "Files:");
                for (File file : files) {
                    Log.i(DEBUG, "%s (%s) - " + file.getName() + file.getId());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Handle Exception here
            Log.i(DEBUG, "Exception: " + exception.toString());
        }
    }

    private static Credential getCredentials(final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        String DEBUG = "LOGLEARN";
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = AlarmReceiver.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        java.io.File tokenFolder = new java.io.File(Environment.getDataDirectory() +
                java.io.File.separator + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH);
        if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
            Log.i(DEBUG, "Token Folder does not exist " + tokenFolder.toString());
            tokenFolder.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
            Log.i(DEBUG, "Token Folder still does not exist " + tokenFolder.toString());
        } else {
            Log.i(DEBUG, "Token Folder now exists " + tokenFolder.toString());
        }

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder build = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES);
        Log.i(DEBUG, "Checkpoint 1");

        build.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder));

        Log.i(DEBUG, "Checkpoint 2");
        build.setAccessType("offline");

        Log.i(DEBUG, "Checkpoint 3");
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = build.build();

        Log.i(DEBUG, "Checkpoint end");

        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

I would expect to get some kind of file list written to LogCat but instead I get the following:

```
 I/LOGLEARN: Starting AlarmReceiver
 I/LOGLEARN: Token Folder does not exist /data/tokens
 I/LOGLEARN: Token Folder still does not exist /data/tokens
 I/LOGLEARN: Checkpoint 1
 I/LOGLEARN: Exception: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /data/tokens
```

Two strange things are happening that I do not understand.

1. It is failing at this line `build.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder));`
2. `tokenFolder.mkdirs();` is not creating a directory as expected and is not throwing an exception.

Also, I do not understand the terminology of the class name `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder` - is this just a class name with a full stop in it or a reference to an inner class or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you eventually get the answer to this *"create /token/ directory"* issue.

If worse comes to worst, and you just need to access the MP3 files where you know their Google Drive path...

- Example: 
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXX/view
- Becomes (via editing with `String` functions):
  https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=XXXXX&export=download

Replace only `XXXXX` with your file ID. The MP3 bytes will now download so either read into a `bytearray` or else use as URL within your MP3 decoder / player.